# How to remove unknown characters from a folder name?

Tags: bash, rename, file-management

I have a Debian 10 machine which is used as a Share server (*Samba Server*).
I go on my Mac, I create a folder `Document.1` in the shared folder.
When I go to my Linux Debian machine, I find myself with an unknown character (square with question marks) in place of the `.`. I want to use a script to remove these characters. I could do it by hand but I have a very large tree.

I don't know if I was clear enough, don't hesitate if you need more information.

Update : I also do it with spaces at the end of folder names (for example = `Document1` )

I thank you in advance if you have a little idea of **BASH** script.
Have a nice day.

```
root@debian:/home/ekip/Documents# ls -lb
    total 20
    drwxr-xr-x  3 ekip ekip 4096 juil. 21 09:33 deuxpoints
    drwxr-xr-x 10 ekip ekip 4096 juil. 21 16:12 espace
    drwxr-xr-x  2 ekip ekip 4096 juil. 22 16:47 script
    drwxrwxrwx  2 ekip ekip 4096 juil. 22 15:14 TEST
    -rw-r--r--  1 root  root    20 juil. 22 17:00 unicode.sh
    root@debian:/home/ekip/Documents#
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `ls` in the directory containing the problematic directories.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe read F029 in the square.

Comment: Share the output of `/bin/ls -l|od -c`

Comment: Would it be correct to summarize your issue as: When filenames of files/directories on a Samba share have been assigned on macOS, then the names containing dots and spaces show up with unknown symbols on Debian?

Comment: @Ekip_DetP If one of the answers solved your issue, then consider accepting that answer.  Accepting an answer marks your question as resolved. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file with a character that you cannot type or appears as a `?` when `ls`ed in the Terminal, you can still use a wildcard to interact with it:

```
$ touch 'neat↑file'
$ ls -l n*
-rw-r--r--    1 dopeghoti users         0 Jul 22 08:20 neat?file
```

The `?` is not a literal `?`, as you can see from the command used to create it.

However, we can still reference it even if we don't have the ability to type a `↑` (or indeed see which character it is):

```
$ mv neat?file neat_file
$ ls n*
-rw-r--r--    1 dopeghoti users         0 Jul 22 08:20 neat_file
```

`?` in `bash` (and most shells) is a wildcard for 'precisely one character'.

Comment: This does not help much regarding the question AMA: "I want to use a script to remove these characters", for a "very large tree". It would be pretty unsafe to `grep` the output of `ls` for questions marks (do not parse `ls` output!). And anyway, how would the file be named instaead? A filename can have an explicit question mark. Two different files with non-printable characters may appear alike with `ls`, eg. `test?` and `test?`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `detox` command does a pretty god job at cleaning up braindamaged filenames. Then you would throw some sed or awk for the remaining job if you have any.

Ref. https://linux.die.net/man/1/detox

I used to do it with bash scripts but they quickly become convoluted and slow.

Comment: Oh damn, The people who downvote answers without providing reasons just make me stop trying to help on SE. Certainly, there are obviously BAD answers sometimes. May be mine was not bash as expected, but as I say, there will be limits to what can be *automated* with a shell script here AMA. With a *very large tree* as stated, any use of jokers comes with a serious danger of collision etc.